# Setting Locale Dynamically for index.html using JET Translation Bundles

Tags: javascript, html, translation, oracle-jet

I have a query regarding setting `locale` dynamically for `index.html`. We have a hard-coded text status strings in `index.html` file. How can we go about localizing the strings in index.html file, using the `JET Translation Bundles`?

Answer (score 0):

The format for defining the localized strings are provided in https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet112/jet/developer/GUID-F3E45F96-FAE2-4830-A2FA-16B3740B1A2D.htm#JETDG-GUID-C1DD4E38-34F8-48F8-A5A7-E4F793F65A69

After defining the appropriate localized strings use    oj.Translations.getTranslatedString(key)
 method to fetch the localized string.